# For-loop overwriting array once finished

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, shuffle

In the code below, I've tried to make an array shuffler. This'll shuffle a character array (`charArray`) as many times as `runTimes` dictates, storing each of these arrays in the two dimensional array, `shuffledArrays`. The problem is when the program finishes the for-loop, for some reason, it sets all of the arrays to the last one added.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] charArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}; //Array to be shuffled
        int runTimes = 3; //Amount of shuffled arrays to create

        char[][] shuffledArrays = new char[runTimes][charArray.length];;


        for (int x = 0; x != runTimes; x++) {
            shuffledArrays[x] = shuffleArray(charArray);

            System.out.print("IN FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[" + x + "] = ");
            System.out.println(shuffledArrays[x]);
        }

        System.out.print("OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[0] = ");
        System.out.println(shuffledArrays[0]);

        System.out.print("OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[1] = ");
        System.out.println(shuffledArrays[1]);

        System.out.print("OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[2] = ");
        System.out.println(shuffledArrays[2]);

    }

    private static char[] shuffleArray(char[] array) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(array.length);

            char temp = array[randomIndexToSwap];

            array[randomIndexToSwap] = array[x];

            array[x] = temp;
        }

        return array;

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `shuffledArray` doesn't return a new array. It returns the same array passed in. And you always pass the same array in. So you're adding the same `char[]` array to `shuffledArrays` lots of times.

Comment: It does return the same array, but it is changed inside of `shuffleArray()`. Which is why the `"IN FOR LOOP: "` line prints out three different arrays, all shuffled version of the original. What I don't understand is why when it leaves the for-loop, all the arrays it just printed out have now turned into the same value.

Comment: Because you're shuffling the same array over and over. But at the end you've still only got one array.

Comment: Consider to use Collections.shuffle: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the original array, you need to change the copy of the array e.g.

```
private static char[] shuffleArray(char[] inArray) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] array = inArray.clone();
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(array.length);
        char temp = array[randomIndexToSwap];
        array[randomIndexToSwap] = array[x];
        array[x] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
IN FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[0] = dcfaeb
IN FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[1] = edcbaf
IN FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[2] = bfaced
OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[0] = dcfaeb
OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[1] = edcbaf
OUT OF FOR LOOP: shuffledArrays[2] = bfaced
```

Comment: Agree with this solution, but you could also point out that OP should change `char[][] shuffledArrays = new char[runTimes][charArray.length];` to `char[][] shuffledArrays = new char[runTimes][];`. As it stands the allocated 2nd dimension is never used.

Answer (score 1):

As you always return the *SAME* array the last one is affects all of them. You need to return a copy or pass a copy, like:

```
private static char[] shuffleArray(char[] array) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(array.length);

        char temp = array[randomIndexToSwap];

        array[randomIndexToSwap] = array[x];

        array[x] = temp;
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You observed three states of *the same* array. The `System.out.println()` statement of the first iteration of the for loop prints the first state, which is at that very moment for example `f, b, c, e, a, d`. Then the second iteration you shuffle the same array again, for example `a, e, b, f, c, d`. The third iteration idem dito.

Now `shuffledArrays[0]`, `shuffledArrays[1]` and `shuffledArrays[2]` point to the very same array.